# Missing mil.h header when compiling with ocam

Tags: c++, cmake

I wrote a shared object library that has as dependency one external library called mil.h that it is also a .so and is located in my /opt/ folder. I added it to my project through `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `LINK_DIRECTORIES` from Cmake, it compiled and generated a .so. Although when I try to compile my main.cpp using the generated .so GCC returns an error saying that mil.h was not found. If `ldd` my .so I checked that the reference to mil.h is there. *I don't understand the reason behind the error and how can I correct it*. The original idea is to my project to depend only from the.so I wrote since I will be calling it from another programming language later.

My Cmake file from my .so is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(OcamShared LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


#Adding external libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/lib)

#Adding internal libraries
add_library(
   ocam2-sdk SHARED
   ocam2_sdk.h
   ocam2_pvt.h
   ocam2_sdk.c
   )

add_library(OcamShared SHARED
 OcamShared_global.h
 ocamshared.cpp
 ocamshared.h
)

target_compile_definitions(OcamShared PRIVATE OCAMSHARED_LIBRARY ocam2-sdk)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(OcamShared libmil.so)
```

While my main.cpp Cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(OcamShared_teste LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    /home/flidemo/OCAM_tests/OCAM_teste/OcamShared
    )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    /home/flidemo/OCAM_tests/OCAM_teste/build-OcamShared-Desktop-Debug
    )

add_executable(OcamShared_teste main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OcamShared_teste PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
target_link_libraries(OcamShared_teste PRIVATE libOcamShared.so)
```

The exact error is

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/OcamShared_teste.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/flidemo/OCAM_tests/OCAM_teste/OcamShared_teste/main.cpp:2:0:
/home/flidemo/OCAM_tests/OCAM_teste/OcamShared/ocamshared.h:5:17: fatal error: mil.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am including mil.h by using `#include <mil.h>` but the error persists if I use `#include "mil.h"`

Edit: `mil.h`lives in the */opt/matrox_imaging/mil* folder and it is included on the path of the compiling chain from my .so, which is the only instance using this library.

Comment: The angle-brackets style (`#include <x.h>`) is reserved for *system headers* or things in your incude path. Anything you put in your source directory requires `#include "x.h"` which is relative to your source path. Where does `mil.h` live? Is it supposed to be in your include path?

Comment: My suggestion: read the documentation of [cmake](https://cmake.org/), and the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [CPP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) (its preprocessor). Since `gcc` and `g++` accept the `-H` option

Comment: Notice that **`cmake`, `gcc`, `g++` are all [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software)** (or free software). **You are allowed to study their source code, and to modify it to your specific needs.** However, you could need several months of work; consider perhaps subcontracting some of it.

Comment: You add `/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include` to include directories, yet `mil.h` is in `/opt/matrix_imaging/mil` and you try to include it via `<mil.h>`. Either move the header to `/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include` or add `/opt/matrix_imaging/mil` to your include directories.

Comment: Shared library `libOcamShared.so` contains neither `mil.h` header nor include path for it. So you need `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include)` for `main.cpp` too.

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski mil.h is indeed in `opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include` I double checked it. What it is present in `/matrox_imaging/mil/` is two directories: `\include/` where `mil.h` lies and `/lib/` where `libmil.so` is located.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is there a way in that I can include `mil.h` header and path in `libOcamShared.so, so I can avoid including it again in `main.cpp`? As I said my final goal is to use this shared library in another language, so as little coupling as possible would be ideal.

Comment: Once again, shared library cannot contain a header file. If you want to use a library for compile an application, you need to ship the library with the header file. If you want to build that application in another language, you need to write a header file suitable for that language.

Comment: Then I will fallback to IPC processing, probably shared memory then. Perhaps creating a background service that communicate to a a third .so that effectively can be called by the other language. Thanks for the attention @Tsyvarev.

Comment: Better than that I can just add where mil.h to OS default directory search path using `ldconfig`